# Trying to get LetsEncrypt to run on GlassFish

Tags: java, glassfish

I've been trying to install LetsEncrypt on my server. My server is running on GlassFish and I've been getting a whole bunch of challenge errors from all of the letsencrypt services, any help would be appreciated!

System Info:
CentOS 7
Webservice: GlassFish

Here are some images of the error codes:

[image: Error Code in zerossl.com]

[image: Error code using certbot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in your GlassFish configuration but because LetsEncrypt services are not able to find the letsencrypt file under the url displayed in the error (starting with `https://mdjdreview.com/index.php/.well-known/acme-challenge/...`).

This is because your GlassFish does not serve the file, but redirects the URL to EdgeMAX application, which just returns a 404 page - not found.

I recommend to follow the steps in the letsencrypt guide here: https://certbot.eff.org/#centosrhel7-other, and use the `certonly` option with `--standalone`. You would need to stop GlassFish (or a proxy server listening on port 80) for a while, as this option needs to run a standalone HTTP server and it would collide with GlassFish.

Letsencrypt requires your server to serve the letsencrypt file from the specified URL, and with your current configuration, it is not possible to do it with GlassFish.